# YYYY-MM-DD formatted date is taking previous date when we are in eastern time zone

Tags: javascript

Javascript date conversion is taking the previous date.

```
new Date('2020-03-02')
```

In the same time zone if i use YYYY/MM/DD format it is working fine. (new Date('2020/03/02'))
[image]

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD` is always in UTC format.

Comment: Is there aby specific reason that taking previous time only when i am in Eastern time zone

Comment: Yes, if your 5 hours behind UTC, it will be the previous day if the time portion is before 5am.  And just using the date will be before 5am.  If you want to use UTC dates you could add the UTC offset.. eg. `'2020-03-02T00:00:00-0500'`